# Hints for counting and assigning to variable

Tags: matlab, loops, count

I am tasked to create a script counting eruptions with `VEI >=3` for each year. Then display on screen about the volcano name and date if `VEI >=3` and save the yearly number of eruptions with `VEI >=3`.

Data is in an excel file. After loading the file, here is what my script wrote:

```
% read the data
[volcname,volcVEI,starteruptyear,starteruptmonth] = textread(inFile,'%s %f %f     %f %*f %*f %*f %*f','headerlines',1,'delimiter',',');

%theVEI is an index for all the VEI >=3
theVEI = find(volcVEI >= 3)
theYear = starteruptyear(theVEI);

Yearvolc = unique(theYear);

startyear = min(Yearvolc);
endyear = max(Yearvolc);

for i = theVEI
    %theVEI(year)
    % Using the index value defined by i, I pluck out 
    screenprint = sprintf('The volcano %s, erupted on year %g, the %g month, with an intensity of VEI     %g',volcname{i},starteruptyear(i),starteruptmonth(i),volcVEI(i));
    disp(screenprint)
end
```

Example data:

[image]

Comment: What is your actual question? Does something in your code fail? Do you get an unexpected result? If you tell us **exactly** where you are having problems we will be more able to help

Comment: I want to count the number of eruptions with VEI >=3 for each year.

Comment: I'd recommend reading the documentation for [`unique`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) as there is an example given there that covers your case